# delete not numerical, "space input" value from the array

Tags: jquery, arrays, splice

I'm struggling with the following

I have an input field where a person should enter his name. The porblem occurs when they enter a double name, like "dow jones". I need to get rid of the space input, to get "dowjones".

This is what I have tried so far but it doesnt' work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#b").click(function(){
    var player = $("#1").val().trim();
alert(player);

    var newPlayerToObject = player;

    var spaceInputIndex = $.inArray(' ',newPlayerToObject);

alert(spaceInputIndex+" index of space");
alert(newPlayerToObject+" new player to object var");

                if(spaceInputIndex > -1){

                    // one solution, not working for me
                    delete  newPlayerToObject[spaceInputIndex];

                    // the other solution, also not working
                    //newPlayerToObject.splice(spaceInputIndex,2);


                }


    alert(newPlayerToObject+" new player without space");
 });            
 });
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HWKQY/1687/

the code finds the index of the space input. But splice method won't work.

I have read on this forum that it could be because of the different understanding of arrays in jQuery and javascripting... But I'm not that handy with the coding yet...

Could please someone explain what I'm doing wrong? And how can I do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of spaces is fairly simple with a regex :

```js
var someString = "This is a string with spaces";

alert( someString.replace(/ /g, '') ); // 'g' is for multiple instances (global)
```